# Disproof of an integrability claim

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

I am trying to disprove the following claim:

> Let $f:[0,1] \to \Bbb R$.  If $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left (\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n f\left( \frac kn\right) \right) $$ exists, then $f$ is integrable in the interval $[0,1]$.

I tried giving a counterexample by selecting $$f(x)=D(x)= \begin{cases}
1,  & \text{$x \in \Bbb Q$} \\
0, & \text{$x \notin \Bbb Q$}
\end{cases}$$
Obviously for every $k,n\in\Bbb N$ we have that $\frac kn\in \Bbb Q$.

This means that:
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left (\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n f\left( \frac kn\right) \right) = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left (\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n 1 \right) = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left (\frac 1n n \right)=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left (1 \right)= 1.$$
Thus the limit exists, yet $f$ is known to not be integrable in any interval, which is a disproof of the claim.
Is this a valid disproof of the claim was the first equality problematic?

Comment: It looks just fine to me.